# Axios not entering in catch - response interceptor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jwt, refresh-token

I have react single page application and authentication with access token(jwt) and refresh token. I'm using axios interceptors to handle it.

**The code in `catch` is not proccessed:**

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => response,
            async (error) => {
                const config = error.config

                const headers = error.response?.headers

                const TokenExpiredHeader =
                    headers && headers['token-expired'] === 'true'

                if (
                    error?.response?.status === 401 &&
                    TokenExpiredHeader &&
                    !config._retry
                ) {
                    config._retry = true
                    return axios
                        .post('/Tokens/Refresh', {
                            accessToken: localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
                        })
                        .then((res) => {
                            localStorage.setItem(
                                'accessToken',
                                res.data.accessToken
                            )
                            return axios(config)
                        })
                        .catch((refreshErr) => {
                            // This code is not executed when receive error!
                            localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
                            history.push(Paths.login())
                            return Promise.reject(error)
                        })
                } else {
                    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
                    history.push(Paths.login())
                }

                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
```

Comment: It looks like you are potentially running into an intercept loop, since both are using what would appear to be the same axios instance. BTW since you are already using `async` you can do `const response = await axios.post(...)` for improved readability, instead of the old style then..catch. I'd also suggest resolving the access token before your API calls, and then storing in local storage, to avoid the issue you are running into.

Comment: I know I did it with try-catch but couldnt handle catch so I went to then-catch. NVM but if I change ```return axios``` to just ```axios``` it enters in catch but not returning the response in my components...

Comment: Also I dont want to change anything more related to the authentication because I handled many cases like loging in 2 devices, then delete the account from one device and etc and I think this is the last step

Comment: It just seems odd that you are trying to refresh the token after failure, rather than before the call. Generally if you are running into auth failure like this, then the login session is generally considered expired. What is your intent here?

Comment: Nothing concrete. I just started doing it that way because I followed the best practices on internet. Yes, in your why Ill have 1 req-res less which sounds a little bit better. Ill try it. What you will suggest me ? In request interceptor -> jwt_decode -> if expired -> refresh ? The problem is I handled yet every scenario but I stuck on this.

Comment: I have to think more on your idea because it may handle some dirty scenarios better maybe.

Comment: If you have some working examples please send it here :)

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from the comments, the approach we use in our frontend project is to delegate the logic of keeping the token fresh to an interval timer. The thinking here:

- Send the user to the logout page if there was a failure to refresh the auth token
- Not give the impression to the user that they can do an action on a potentially invalid API access, which is shared with the login session
- The best magic is when the code doesn't create flows that are hard for the next developer to understand

Additionally, some of this philosophy is also described in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue) for Keycloak, for Vue apps. Keycloak being an open source OpenID/SAML authentication provider, sponsored by RedHat.

In our code (Quasar/Vue3 app), the we use an axios request interceptor to inject the Keycloak JWT bearer token:

```
  const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    baseURL: appConfig.apiUrl,
    withCredentials: true
  };

  api = axios.create(axiosConfig);

  api.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      // Only deal with bearer token, if keycloak is enabled
      if (app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak) {
        const keycloak = app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak;

        if (keycloak.authenticated) {
          const keycloak = app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak;
          const token = keycloak.token as string;
          if (token && config.headers) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          }
        }
      }
      return config;
    }
  );
```

Then our code is essentially a slightly modified version of the example provided in the Keycloak documentation page. What's important here is what it is trying to do, as opposed to the code itself which you'll need to adjust to what you are doing:

```
  setInterval(() => {
    keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
      if (refreshed) {
        Vue.$log.info('Token refreshed' + refreshed);
      } else {
        Vue.$log.warn('Token not refreshed, valid for '
          + Math.round(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
      }
    }).catch(() => {
      Vue.$log.error('Failed to refresh token');
    });
  }, 6000)
```

There are probably other suggestions on how to go about this, but I always prioritise 'readable and maintainable' for my code, so it influences my implementation choices.

Comment: Thank you. Very gentle and detailed explanation. But since you refresh the jwt on interval what will happen when user initially enter private route ? The jwt is not refreshed, the timer will happens soon for example.

Comment: On login the JWT should be valid and your refresh period should be shorter than the expiry period of the token. So it should be valid at any time you need to use it, unless it failed to refresh and is expired.

Comment: Im not fully understand it. For example: no browser opened, user is logged in with expired jwt, he run the browser on myapp.com/profile. Here the jwt might be not valid and you have to refresh the jwt when user open your site I guess.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for the respones it is not answering my question but it is much valuble. I fix my problem as changed the statement to  error?.response?.status === 401 &&
                    TokenExpiredHeader &&
                    !config._retry &&
                    config.url !== '/Tokens/Refresh'
It is not related to axios but to my stupidy.